# How to ensure in AngularJS, that the data is loaded first before it is used?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, anonymous-function

I guess it's a classic JavaScript and asynchronism issue, but I didn't get, how to solve it. I'm building a fronend with AngularJS. Later the date will be retrieved from an API, but now I'm simply read it from a local `JSON` file. Here is the code:

**`app.js`**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('portfolio', []);

    app.controller('ProjectItemController', function() {
        this.projectItemData = dataProjectItem;
        console.log(dataProjectItem);
    });

    var dataProjectItem;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', config['base_url'] + '/dummy-data/project-item.json');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        dataProjectItem = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send();

})();
```

**`list.phtml`**

```
<div id="projects" ng-app="portfolio">
    <div class="projectItem" ng-controller="ProjectItemController as projectItem">
        <div class="project-image"><img ng-src="{{projectItem.projectItemData._embedded.images[0].src}}" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, that on the server (and sometimes locally as well), the data has not yet been loaded and script is already trying to use `projectItemData`.

I've tried to solve it with a anonymous function, but it hasn't worked:

```
app.controller('ProjectItemController', function() {
    this.projectItemData = (function () {
        var dataProjectItem;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', config['base_url'] + '/dummy-data/project-item.json');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            dataProjectItem = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.send();
        return this.dataProjectItem;
    })();
});
```

<s>(1) How to make the script always load the data first and only then use it? And since it's currently taking place in the AngularJS context: (2) Is there a specific Angular solution for this problem?</s>

**EDIT**

**How to solve this problem in AngularJS?**

Comment: Use Angular's built-in ajax service, `$http`.  Not only is it a simpler API than `XMLHttpRequest`, but it will also work properly with the data bindings

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as proposed in the comments [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is the easiest way to do ajax requests in Angular.

You could also use [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) if you're having a RESTful backend that you're interacting with.

Please have a look at the demo below and here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/9c2uvLa0/).

It shows the usage of `$http` service.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('wikiService', function($http) {

  var wikiService = {
    getJSONP: function(country) {
      return $http.jsonp('http://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?titles=' + country.name.toLowerCase() + '&rawcontinue=true&action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
    },
    post: function() {
      return $http.post('/echo/json/', {
        test: 'testdata',
        delay: 2
      });
    },
    get: function(url) {
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  };

  return wikiService;
});

app.controller('MainController', function($scope, wikiService) {

  wikiService.getJSONP({
    name: 'germany'
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.wikiData = data.data;
  });

  /*
  // commented here because of CORS
  wikiService.post().then(function(data) {
    console.log('posted', data);
  });

  wikiService.get('/echo/json/').then(function(data) {
    console.log('get data', data);
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log('Error: ', reason);
  });

  // the following request is not correct to show the error handler
  wikiService.get('/badurl').then(function(data) {
    console.log('get data', data);
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log('Error: ', reason.status == 404 ? 'page not found' : reason);
  });*/

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="ng-error"></div>
    <pre ng-bind="wikiData | json"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what is wrong with my solution? I'd like to use it and actually it should work, but it doesn't. Why?